# Error ROS2 Humble slam_toolbox message filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' queue full

Tags: python, c++, ros, ros2, slam

I am working with ROS2 Humble on a diffdrive robot.
I am trying to launch slam toolbox but every time i get the error that the queue is full and the message are being dropped. Here is an image of the [slam_toolbox error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVJIh.png).
I am using an RPLidar a1 for the scan data and a Raspberry pi 4 that runs ROS2 humble

First I thought it was because i didn't have a tf_broadcaster from odom->base_link but even after made a broadcaster i got the same error
Here is een image of the [TF Tree after creating broadcaster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwB3O.png)
I also tried to increase the queue size but that didn't help either.

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: The tf tree says "Most Recent Transform 0,0000". Maybe some tfs are broadcasted only once (but I am not sure if this is the cause of the problem)